# Send nested parameters in post request in NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an app that sends data up to a Ruby on Rails server when a user edits an objects, but I'm having trouble sending nested items in the post request. This is my code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

 NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"api_key=%@&code={alpha=%@&description=%@&public=%d}", @"API_KEY", self.alpha.text, self.description.text, self.public.on];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This is what I am getting on the server log:

```
Parameters: {"api_key"=>"API_KEY", "code"=>"{alpha=ALPHA", "description"=>"", "public"=>"1}", "username"=>"USERNAME", "identifier"=>"IDENTIFIER"}
```

How can I change the iOS part so the server won't recognize that part of it as a string. Also, I don't want to use something like ASIHTTPRequest just for one part of my app.

Comment: You need to URL escape the nested param portion. Since that's all part of your literal, you can do it literally: `&code=%%7Balpha%%3D%@%%26description%%3D%@...`

Comment: @JasonCoco The server still treats the nested part as a string: `Parameters: {"api_key"=>"API_KEY", "code"=>"{alpha="ALPHA", "description"=>"", "public"=>"1}", "username"=>"USERNAME", "identifier"=>"IDENTIFIER"}`